# How to make text overlay on image stable regardless of resizing?

Tags: clojurescript, tailwind-css

I have a cart button with a cart image and a number (of items) that I'm trying to position on top of the image using tailwind. I'm using a clojurescript wrapper for the tailwind library, and here is the code:

```
(defn show-cart-btn []
  [:button (tw style/button [:inline-flex :justify-between :p-2] {:on-click #(e/cart-shown (not @s/cart-shown?)) :title (str @s/cart-count " item(s) in cart")})
   ;;[:div "Cart"]
   [:img (tw [:w-20] {:src "img/svg/icon-cart.svg"})]
   [:div (tw [:absolute :ml-6 :mt-3 :font-bold]) @s/cart-count]]) ;; it's absolute and there are margins.
```

Notice the last line where I have positioned the text, the "cart-count" shows as absolute.
But the problem is that resizing the webpage moves the position of the text on top of the cart, but I want it to be contained within the cart image when the webpage size is changed. How can I do that?

[image: screenshot of the cart]

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to try my best to provide a clean solution to the problem you are facing. It might not be a generic solution, but I hope it will be on point.

You are not trying to put an overlay on any image, but specifically on a state-dependent, context-bound icon. There are some UX constraints regarding this use case:

- the text must be 2 or 3 characters maximum (9, 9+, 99, 99+),
- the icon and it's different states must be self-explanatory.

Relying on CSS to solve this is fair. But there's a simpler way: regular and simple SVG. Which is by the way recommended by Tailwind.

I noticed you are using the [HeroIcon UI](https://github.com/sschoger/heroicons-ui) Cart icon. Here is the icons's SVG, under MIT license:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
  <path class="heroicon-ui" d="M17 16a3 3 0 1 1-2.83 2H9.83a3 3 0 1 1-5.62-.1A3 3 0 0 1 5 12V4H3a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h3a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1h14a1 1 0 0 1 .9 1.45l-4 8a1 1 0 0 1-.9.55H5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h12zM7 12h9.38l3-6H7v6zm0 8a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm10 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z"/>
</svg>
```

Let's transform it to hiccup using [Html To Hiccup](https://htmltohiccup.herokuapp.com):

```clj
[:svg {:height "24", :width "24", :viewBox "0 0 24 24"}
 [:path {:class "heroicon-ui"
         :d     "M17 16a3 3 0 1 1-2.83 2H9.83a3 3 0 1 1-5.62-.1A3 3 0 0 1 5 12V4H3a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h3a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1h14a1 1 0 0 1 .9 1.45l-4 8a1 1 0 0 1-.9.55H5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h12zM7 12h9.38l3-6H7v6zm0 8a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm10 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z"}]]
```

We can now:

- change the viewBox width from 24 to 48,
- change the icon width from 24 to 48,
- add a text SVG element,
- make it a component.

```clj
(defn CartIconCounter
  "HeroIcon SVG icon from https://github.com/sschoger/heroicons-ui/blob/master/svg/icon-cart.svg"
  [props amount]
  [:svg (merge {:height "24", :width "48", :viewBox "0 0 48 24"}
               props)
   [:path {:class "heroicon-ui"
           :d     "M17 16a3 3 0 1 1-2.83 2H9.83a3 3 0 1 1-5.62-.1A3 3 0 0 1 5 12V4H3a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h3a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1h14a1 1 0 0 1 .9 1.45l-4 8a1 1 0 0 1-.9.55H5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h12zM7 12h9.38l3-6H7v6zm0 8a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm10 0a1 1 0 1 0 0-2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2z"}]
   [:text {:class     "icon-text font-bold fill-current"
           :font-size "0.75rem"
           :y         "18"
           :x         "22"}
    (str amount)]])

(defn show-cart-btn []
  [:button (tw style/button [:inline-flex :justify-between :p-2]
               {:on-click #(e/cart-shown (not @s/cart-shown?))
                :title    (str @s/cart-count " item(s) in cart")})
   [CartIconCounter {:style {}} @s/cart-count]])
```

You can customise the `<text>` element using the `icon-text` class.
Make sure to keep the `fill-current` Tailwind class as explained in [Tailwind's documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/fill/).

As I said at the beginning, this answer might not be a generic one, but I think this solution is simple because:

- it (seems to) solves your problem,
- it introduces 0 dependencies,
- it doesn't rely on any trick,
- it makes sure your cart icon is going to behave the same everywhere.

Comment: The code shows the number but not the cart. How do I show the cart as well?

Comment: You are right there is a mistake in my code, let me edit it. The :d attribute for :path is misplaced. Sorry about this.